# Move sharepoint list data to db table

Tags: list, content-database

I have sharepoint application which takes more time to load. So i planned to move data from certain list to another table in same database. Since alluserdata table in sharepoint stores data from all lists and we use procedure to get data from sharepoint database. Is my decision to move data from alluserdata table is right or not? Is there any other solution to make the application load fast?

Comment: No, not right, not right at all. In fact it's the very antithesis of right. You need to employ someone with SharePoint experience to help out I suspect. SharePoint can run quickly when configured correctly and without recourse to meddling with the internal data structure.

Comment: Actually i choose this method because when i try to load my sharepoint page i am getting error page. When i look into that error in log file, i can find that is because of SQL query timeout error.

Comment: Your configuration (or customisation) of SharePoint is at fault then. Trying to redesign the way in which SharePoint works will not help you here.

Comment: The same instance works fine for one year. Now only we are facing this issue.

Comment: regardless @suren, manipulating and even reading data inside sharepoint databases through SQL is not only bad practice, but it flags your environment as unsupported. I would further diagnose why your application loads slower than satisfactory. Maybe you can specify what the application is doing.